# WiFi or Bluetooth to communicate between several Arduinos and a Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, communication, wireless

So I want to set up a network of outdoor sensors (temperature and humidity) connected to an Arduino (and at some point a second or third Arduino further away with its own sensors). Then I'd like this Arduino to wirelessly transmit this data to a Raspberry Pi running some sort of server that can receive the data and then upload it to the cloud. I'm assuming WiFi is the best method to do this because of range and the number of devices at once? Would I just have to get each Arduino a WiFi module and what kind of range can I expect from this setup?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105211/discussion-on-question-by-cwille97-wifi-or-bluetooth-to-communicate-between-seve).

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest using WIFI (ESP8266) as you need to create a local network in which all devices will communicate to single host connected to the same network. If range will be issue you can use LORAWAN network for the same. LORAWAN provide high network range and if industrial gateway is used you can connect 10000 nodes(arduino in your case) communicating to the single server at a time.Else WIFI will the good.

Comment: If I get an ESP8266-01 module to connect to an Arduino Mega or Uno, will the board still have enough digital and analog slots for some temp and humidity sensors?

Comment: Yes. ESP8266-01 require only UART pins to communicate with the arduino, so you have many pins left for another work.